# Поменять местами максимальный и минимальный элемент в односвязном списке

Tags: c++

Нужно поменять местами максимальный и минимальный элемент в списке. Получилось найти их и вывести значения, но поменять местами не получается.

```
    void Find_Min_Max_SingleList (SingleList *Head) {
    double max;
    double min;
    SingleList *ptr = Head;
    min = ptr->Data;
    max = ptr->Data;
    while (ptr) {
        if (ptr->Data > max) {
            max = ptr->Data;
        }
        if (ptr->Data < min) {
            min = ptr->Data;
        }
        ptr = ptr->Next;
    }
    cout << "max: " << max << endl;
    cout << "min: " << min << endl;
}
```

Comment: Если запомнить указатели на **предшествующие** им (min и max) элементы списка (учтите, если min или max первый в списке, то соответствующий ему указатель на предшественника должен быть или 0 или указывать на Head (это м.б. необычно, но код скорее всего станет приятней)), то это сделает решение задачи очевидным.

Comment: Пока не могу понять как мне зафиксировать эти указатели.

Comment: Что значит зафиксировать? Просто в дополнение к переменным min и max объявите указатели, например `Singlelist **pmin = &Head, **pmax = &Head;`, которые и будут после цикла указывать на нужные элементы списка и замените свой ptr на `Singlelist **ptr = &Head`. Далее идете `while ((*ptr)->next) if ((*ptr)->next->data < min) { ...` ну и т.д., а в конце  цикла переход к следующей структуре `ptr = &((*ptr)->next)` Для перехода на указатель на структуру погуглите `container_of` макро

Comment: Переменные числовые?

Answer (score 1):

В принципе в данном случае можно и забыть про то, что это односвязный список и просто поменять значения:

```
void Swap_Min_Max_SingleList (SingleList *Head) {
    SingleList *pmin = Head;
    SingleList *pmax = Head;
    SingleList *ptr = Head;
    while (ptr) {
        if (ptr->Data > pmax->Data) {
            pmax = ptr;
        }
        if (ptr->Data < pmin->Data) {
            pmin = ptr;
        }
        ptr = ptr->Next;
    }
    std::iter_swap(pmin, pmax); // #include <algorithm>
}
```

В данном случае это будет работать не сильно хуже, чем менять связи в списке, но если конструктор копирования отсутствует или вызов его достаточно затратен, то придётся уже менять связи.

Comment: Менять значения в связном списке — моветон.

Comment: @0andriy: Нет. Существуют соображения в пользу и того, и другого подхода.